# Mysql regex - как удалить после символа по шаблону?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть значения в таблице, с числами с точкой, например 24.25 , 3455.232
Составил запрос, но почему-то он не заменяет на пусто значения после точки (включая точку) - удаляет все значение. Может точку он как-то воспринимает не как символ точки, хотя я ее экранировал.
Может есть отличия в регулярках в SQL и обычных?

```
UPDATE b_iblock_element_property
SET VALUE = REGEXP_REPLACE(VALUE, '\.\d+', '')
WHERE IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID IN (SELECT ID from b_iblock_element WHERE IBLOCK_SECTION_ID = '182') AND IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID = '208'
```

Comment: Не проще было бы хранить числа как числа, а не как строки?

Comment: Это не я так придумал, а те кто лепил битрикс до меня. Кончено проще и правильнее как числа.

Comment: Покажите лучше пример ПОЛНОГО значения поля (2-3 штуки) и результат для них. А то создаётся впечатление, что регулярка тут - как из пушки по воробьям.

Comment: Это и есть полное значение 3455.232

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю почему, но переделал регулярку и обозначил конец строки - так заработало.

```
UPDATE b_iblock_element_property
SET VALUE = REGEXP_REPLACE(VALUE, '(\.{1}[0-9]{1,4})$', '')
WHERE IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID = '6409' AND IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID = '208'
```

Comment: тестируйте регулярки на сайтах типа regex101.com

Comment: первая регулярка там и протестирована и она корректная